# What's the workflow to contribute to an open source project using git pull requests? (eg. via Github)

Tags: git, github, open-source, pull-request

I have a comprehensive step by step description on how I do this and I wanted to share it here  so developers can benefit from it (I'll answer my own question).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Since changes contributed to open source projects will have to be peer reviewed it's common to see a workflow which relies on git pull requests. Pull requests are not allowed from directly cloned repos (you need your own fork). So these are the steps I follow to maintain a healthy fork and contribute to an open source periodically:

**Note: Steps 1, 2 and 3 are only done once per project on a single development machine to set everything up.**

**Note 2: If the open source project that you will be contributing to doesn't use main as the default working branch you will have to replace all reference to 'main' in the commands of steps 4) and 7) below with the name of that branch (e.g. master).**

**1)** Make sure you're working locally on your "fork" of the project rather than on a cloned repository pointing to the project as origin. In order to fork a Github project go to https://github.com/entity/project , click on "Fork" and choose a suitable GitHub account for the fork eg. your personal Github account. Note that your forked project "origin" will be no longer the original project repo but your own fork on Github. Be careful with privacy if you're forking a private project since you probably don't want your fork to be public.

**2)** Clone your own project fork into your development machine and cd into that directory.

```
git clone git@github.com:yourgithubuser/project.git
```

**3)** Add the original project repo as upstream repository in your forked project.

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com:entity/project.git
```

The original main project repo is now "upstream" but not "origin"

**And now comes the work loop that you'll repeat when you work with your forked project:**

**4)** Before starting your work always make sure the main branch of your forked repo is synchronized with the main branch of the original project repo:

```
git checkout main &&
git fetch upstream &&
git merge upstream/main &&
git push origin main
```

**5)** Create a new branch in your project fork for the specific fixes that you want to contribute (name it after either a bugfix, a tracker issue, a documentation section, etc) and switch to it.

```
git checkout -b myfixes
```

This automatically creates the branch and switches to it. **Make sure the branch does not exist already**. You might also want to get rid of your old fix branches that have already been merged into the docs (otherwise you'll have tons of useless branches in your project). You can take a look at your local branches by issuing a `git branch` and if in that list you find a branch that has already been merged with the upstream project then you can do:

```
git branch -D myoldfixes &&
git push origin --delete myoldfixes
```

**Important note**: if you were already working on a branch on a different machine and want to continue that work on a new machine you need to redo steps 2, 3 and 4 on the new machine and in step 5 instead of doing ***git checkout -b myfixes*** you should do ***git checkout myfixes*** (remove the -b). Otherwise you can end up with a "detached head" state which is not good (kind of an anonymous branch)

**6)** Work on that branch (eg. myfixes) and commit your changes:

```
git commit -a -m "My fixes"
```

(Alternatively you can stage specific files and commit without using -a. You can commit as many times as you want but don't leave uncommited changes in the branch)

**7)** While you were working on your fixes the original upstream project repo might have changed (due to other contributors working on it). So first you'll have to rebase your current branch (myfixes) from the upstream destination branch. In other words you need to replay your fixes on top of that latest work from upstream repo main branch to make sure your commits are still compatible with the latest commits in upstream. This will result in a fast-forward merge for the pull request which is what we want:

```
git checkout myfixes &&
git pull --rebase upstream main
```

**Note 3**: this can result in conflicts but this is normal, fixing them is part of the process (this happens more often on very active projects)

**Note 4**: if you have many commits in the branch and you're a considerate person you might want to [squash your commits into a single one](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/02/19/squashing-github-pull-requests-into-a-single-commit) for the benefit of the maintainer of the original project

**8)** After fixing the conflicts (if any) of the previous step you have applied your fixes on top of the latest version of upstream main. Since the pull requests are initiated from your forked repository on Github you want to keep that one in sync too:

```
git checkout myfixes &&
git push origin myfixes -f
```

**9)** Finally, you can go to Github https://github.com/entity/project (the original project not your fork) and click on "Pull Request". Make sure you choose upstream repo "main" as the destination branch and your forked repo "myfixes" as the source branch (the branch will be automatically removed for you after the pull request is accepted).
Another way to create the pull request is to go to your branches (in your fork of the repo on Github), go to Branches, locate the feature branch and click on "New pull request".

Enjoy!

Comment: Great suggestion! A question: at what point do you update your `origin/master`? Do you update it by merging `myfixes` or by pulling `upstream/master`?

If you pull `upstream/master`, does it mean that you have fix merge conflict once again, even though you've done it while developing `myfixes` and using `git pull --rebase` occassionally?

Comment: Also, it's recommended to [squash your commits so that the pull request only has one big commits](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/02/19/squashing-github-pull-requests-into-a-single-commit)

Comment: You update origin master in 4). You could have a conflict in that merge but if you always do 4) before you start working on the repo then the merge is a no brainer

Comment: Here's another scenario I recently encountered. I open a `new-feature` branch, on which I have 2 commits, `new-feature-basic` (which add the basics) and `new-feature-on-steroid` (which builds upon the basics and add some niceties). 

I want the repo maintainer to be able to accept only the `new-feature-basics` commit, in case he doesn't want the niceties. Do I still create a PR for the entire branch?

Comment: Pull request is per branch. You could send two pull requests for those 2 branches and tell the maintainer "keep the one you prefer, reject the other one". I don't recommend this though, try sending one PR at a time!

Comment: Shouldn't `git push origin myfixes` in step 8 be `git push origin myfixes -f`? Because the `--rebase` from step 7 could make the push fail

Comment: @pomber that's not a good practice, see the footnote on step 7. Best is to to fix the conflicts then you can push safely (this is part of the recommended process)

Comment: @german you are right, but what if you are updating a pull request? after `git pull --rebase upstream master` you need to update origin/myfixes, how would you do that?

Comment: Like this case: https://anavarre.net/how-to-rebase-a-github-pull-request/

Comment: @pomber I see now. I believe you're right about forcing the push to update origin/myfixes I'm adding the -f as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

**6a)** The topic of the commit and format of the commit message are also critical.

#### Commit topic

The commit topic should cover just one logical change. For example, if you were to describe the changes to someone (for example in a commit message, see below) you should not be able to use the word "and" to describe the topic, ex. **not** "Fix bug 123 and update config default." These should be two separate commits.

If you have a bunch of separate issues addressed but uncommitted in your working tree, a great tool is the interactive add. Have your fingers remember this batch of commands, then follow the directions:

```
git add -i
5<CR>
*<CR>
```

You can get fancier with the other options, but that says "show me every change in my working tree and let me pick what to stage."

Then, as usual:

```
git ci
```

#### Commit message

You want to be terse and to the point in the title for people scanning the history, while also providing good details in the body for people in the future (including yourself in six months!) digging in to an issue that involves your change.

My favorite guide to writing good commit messages is the [Erlang/OTP wiki page on good commit messages](https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/writing-good-commit-messages), and to that I'll add that you can't go wrong with the following format:

```
Short (<50 chars) present-tense summary of changes

Previously, <a couple sentences clearly describing the previous behavior
and the resulting customer issue>. 

This commit <a sentence or two clearly describing the code change, and the
resulting expected behavior>.
```